# php cannot recognize javascript cookie

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

I know there is no difference between JavaScript cookies and PHP cookies. yet. I'm setting a cookie with JavaScript, and checking it with PHP.

When I check the cookie with JavaScript, it returns as set. But when I check in PHP, it returns as not set. Here's my code:

**Javascript**

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
   if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
   }
  }

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
 document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function moomoo()
{
var username=getCookie("username");
if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
  alert("Welcome again " + username);
  }
else 
  {
  username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
    setCookie("moomoo",username,365);
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div onclick="moomoo();">click me</div>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["moomoo"])) {
echo ' moomoo worked'; }
else {
echo ' moomoo didnt work';}
```

When I recall the moo moo() script. It alerts with my name

When I load the PHP script it says "moo moo didn't work".

THE FIX!:

Thank you for the suggestions everyone. Alas, the solution was much simpler and as usual, a stupid error. Originally the function moo moo() read:

```
function moomoo()
{
var username=getCookie("**username**");
if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
  alert("Welcome again " + username);
  }
else 
  {
  username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
    setCookie("**username**",username,365);
    }
  }
}
```

Therefore the first time I called the function it set a cookie named "username". Then i changed it to how it is now. So since username was already set, it didn't set moomoo. So the php function couldn't find moomoo cause it was never set. Thank you all!

Comment: Can you `var_dump($_COOKIE);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`When I recall the moo moo() script. It alerts with my name`

It looks like the moomoo variable is not getting set in JavaScript. If your name is alerted, the else block isn't being executed.

Try checking your username cookie in php, and it will display.

Comment: No it is working in javascript. When it sees that no cookie is set it prompts me to enter a username. I entered it, now every time I call the function, it returns "welcome again Kyle". So it is definitely setting the cookie. I just don't understand why I cant recall it in php

Comment: That makes no sense, you are checking the "username" cookie, but not setting it anywhere! You are setting the moomoo cookie, not the username cookie in your else block. Check your logic, therein lies the problem.

Comment: Exactly. I just found my error and updated it above. That was the exact problem. thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the Domain and Path for the cookie.

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString()) + ";domain=.mydomain.com;path=/";
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Note: Change `.mydomain.com` according to your domain.